# Backlight of external keyboard with linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I just bought Redgear Grimm backlight external keyboard to work with linux mint 18.3.
The backlight didn't work initially and after some poking around I found

```
/sys/class/leds/
```

and I am able to turn on the backlight with the following command

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/input25::scrolllock/brightness
```

Now here's the problems

1. Pressing Caps Lock key and Num Lock key disables the backlight  which should not happen
2. After that the backlight doesn't work even when pressing the Num Lock, Caps Lock and Scroll Lock key(which btw should be the actual key for this function.)

The keyboard is fine. Proved by testing it on a Windows laptop.

Comment: Guess: The kernel misinterprets the (USB) HID information from the keyboard (possibly because the HID descriptor is not following the standards), and assigns what it thinks as the scrolllock LED to the backlight. First step is to look at the complete LED assignment for this keyboard, and also the HID descriptor (there are questions on this site describing how to do this).

Comment: Thanks @dirkt. Will search about this.